# Applying color to table according to data coming from server?

Tags: angularjs

Suppose -23% ....0%....100% is my data. For above 0% should show green shades and below red shades . Shades should be darker as the percentage is more . vice versa.

Any Solution?

Comment: share your code so that we can help you

Comment: question is not clear !! this is hex #000000  and this is rgb => rgb(0, 0, 0), what exactly are you talking about ?

Comment: Add jsfiddle link to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for green shades i.e for positive percentage
First I have taken the max percentage and rounded to next 5th multiple value and then divided that rounded value by 5 . If suppose 7.6 is the highest value ,then the rounded value will be 10. so 10/5 is 2 . After this am creating an array. Here array will be [2,4,6,8].
Now am comparing each percentage an applying shades to it.

```
      var dataPositive = [0.12, 4.5, 6.6, 8.9, 0.34, 1.34, 5.6, 9.8, 18.45];
      var maxPositivePercent = Math.max(...dataPositive);
      var roundUpToClosestValue = Math.ceil(maxPositivePercent / 5);
        console.log(roundUpToClosestValue);

        $scope.candlePositive = [1,2,3,4,5];
        for(var i=0 ; i < $scope.candlePositive.length; i++ ) {
            $scope.candlePositive[i] =   $scope.candlePositive[i] 
           *roundUpToClosestValue;
          }
            $scope.candleColorPos = [
            '#C8FFC8',
            '#96FF96',
            '#57f702',
            '#59a033',
            '#2b7c01'
        ];
```

Here is [a link] http://plnkr.co/edit/gaLEPX8n6efskp3I75bU?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-class` directive to add class basis on condition

For ex.

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="shadesVariable" />

<div ng-class="{'class-green': shadesVariable > 0, 'class-red': shadesVariable < 0}"></div>
```

add same name classes in your CSS

```
.class-green {
   color: #808080
}
.class-red {
   color: #FF0000
}
```

If you want to change class value every time then use dynamic value or use inline style